# How to make normal class from a factory in another module?

Tags: python

[The day after] I figured it out- I didn't even know what question to ask.

The solution is to extend the golbals() dictionary of the user module with the dictionary of structure classes I build while parsing the.c and 'h files.
`globals().update(Structures.struct_dict)` is all it took to be able to instantiate my derived classes without having to jump through hoops.

Thanks for the help (whether in comments here or by email), it did get me on the rails.

Original question is below

---

I am new to Python (and to stack overflow) and I am struggling a little with the scoping of objects.

I am making an automated test framework that connects over USB to some machine, then issues commands, reads variables and data streamed by the machine and reacts to it.

In order to facilitate the scripting I wrote a C/C++ preprocessor that slurps all the C source for the machine's code and the resulting map file so that the testers can use the #defines and #enums as well as query variables by their names in C.

All this works fine but to be very useful I need to be able to generate a class for each type of structure I find defined in the source so that when my test code reads the raw data and returns a bytearray the user could do

```
myStruct = SomeStructClass(received_bytearray)
process(myStruct.structure_member_name_from_C_source)
```

I got the parsing done and I can generate the classes OK but I end up with a dictionary of `{name:class}` that is quite unwieldy.

I end up importing the dictionary and requiring the user who writes the test script proper to do weird stuff such as:

```
from Structures import struct_dict
C_struct_name = struct_dict["C_struct_name"]
myStruct = C_struct_name(initial_data)
```

So here is my question:

How can I make it that a simple import from my Structures module defines the new structures I created in Structures in the global scope of the importing script?

In other words, can I automate the second line of my previous code snippet?

In advance thanks a ton!

Comment: I think I might be missing something: if you've got `class SomeStructClass()` laying around in some file, such as your `Structures` module, why not import that instead? `from Structures import SomeStructClass`? Now, if you've got a lot of different variations of these classes, you *could* do `from Structures import *`. Generally speaking, `from foo import *` is frowned upon in Python, but there are cases where it's reasonable, and this might be one of them. Try to make the only exported names in your `Structures` file be the `class`-names, and I think that's clean and acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Actually I am not sure how to automate `C_struct_name = struct_dict["C_struct_name"]` even in my Structures module. I tried composing the source line and evaluating it but then it seems the scope of the C_stuct_name variable is limited to the string I am evaluating.